# How do I disable all input buttons without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, dom

How would I do this without jQuery?

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);
```

It doesn't have to be cross-browser compatible; a solution that only works in Firefox is OK.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === 'submit') {
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to write this code in `<script>
                 $(document).ready(function() { ..... })

           </script>`

Comment: He said WITHOUT jQuery

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

then you could interrogate the DOM to find your submit button. 
[getElementsByTagName reference](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)

A full sample

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        var input = forms[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var y = 0; y < input.length; y++) {
            if (input[y].type == 'submit') {
                input[y].disabled = 'disabled';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, in the time it took me to write that you got 4 answers ;) Guess it must have been an easy question ! :)

Comment: thanks, but two things: you have a hard-coded "input[0]" that needs to be "input[i]", and .toLowerCase() apparently isn't necessary (at least for me in FF 3.5.1).

Answer (score 1):

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName ( 'input' );
for ( var i = 0; i < els.length ; i ++ ) {
 if ( els[i].type == 'submit' ) els[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'true'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but it or something very similar should work.  It could be made better with error and feature checking.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  if(inputs[i].type == 'submit'){
    inputs[i].disabled = 'disabled';
  }
}
```

Comment: needs to be "var i" in javascript, not "int i"